# Change color from more elements then one in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, color-picker

Okay, I have this code which allows me to change the sidebar(HTML page) color by any color I want with a color picker. And it saves (localstorage).

The problem is that I can't figure out how to change more elements with the same code. Like now only the sidebar changes color but I also want something like the buttons changing color with the same color picker.

My situation is something like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wyVQbe

```
/*Set your own color*/
var jscolor;
var defaultColor = (localStorage.getItem("color")) ? localStorage.getItem("color"): "#0078c0";

window.addEventListener("load", startup, false);
function startup() {
  jscolor = document.querySelector(".jscolor");
  if (jscolor) {
    jscolor.value = defaultColor;
    jscolor.addEventListener("input", updateFirst, false);
    jscolor.addEventListener("change", updateAll, false);
    jscolor.select();
  }
  refreshSidebar(defaultColor);
}

function updateFirst(event) {
  refreshSidebar(event.target.value);
}

function refreshSidebar(color) {
  var side = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
  if (side) {
    side.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}

function updateAll(event) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".sidebar").forEach(function(side) {
    side.style.backgroundColor = event.target.value
    localStorage.setItem('color', event.target.value);
  });
}
```

Comment: One thing that you can manage doing is, give same class to all HTML elements you want to change the color and use it to update the color from your color picker

Comment: Which class should I do then? Beceause ".jscolor" is the color picker itself.

Comment: I mean to say, for example give a class "themeColor" along with all the class names you have for your elements which you feel should be updated when your theme changes. Then use  document.getElementsByClassName('themeColor');which gives all the elements with the class. Iterate them and apply background color appropriately

Comment: Yeah okay I got that. But what if I want to change "Color" instead of "Background-Color" from some elements like an Icon?

Comment: Explaining in a comment might be huge so added an answer. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way (might be or might not be ideal )

For all the elements you can differentiate like below elements.

```
<div class='themecolor onlyTextColor'> hello1</div>
<div class='themecolor'> hello2</div>
<div class='themecolor onlyTextColor'> hello3</div>
<div class='themecolor'> hello4</div>
<div class='themecolor'> hello5</div>
```

Where classes with onlyTextColor should update only text color and remaining should update background ( We can have another class like onlyBackground to update only background)

and use something like below (you have tagged Jquery aswell. So I am using jquery below)

```
 $('.themecolor').each(function(){
     localStorage.setItem('color', rgba);
    if ($(this).hasClass("onlyTextColor"))
      {
          $(this).css('color', rgba);
      }
    else
      $(this).css('background-color', rgba);
  }) 
}
```

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MQNPPb)

Comment: I think this is not ideal for me. I also need to save this as localstorage to.

Comment: My situation is something like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wyVQbe

Comment: Isnt it like just setting localstorage as in the updated answer?

Comment: now yes it is, but Could you take a look to the codepen I sended?

Comment: Its actually not showing any color changes/picker. So used it in my codepen :(

Comment: True, You can manually fill a # code  in the input field like #ADD8E6 then you will see it changing.

Comment: are you ok if i use jquery?

Comment: I think I or we have a miss communication here. Ofcourse its ok to use JQuery

Comment: Thanks. This works for the most elements but not on the button. in the codepen it does but when I use it in my code. after pressing (f5) it changes to his original color. weird enoug, and no the button has not a color defind in the css

Comment: hmm. but if it works in codepen, there should be something that's missing in your local. Check if are you seeing any error in console

Comment: I think it is beceause of bootstrap (not sure). The werid thing is that is does change his color with the colorpicker. but it doesn't save it in localstorage i think.

Comment: Can you check it then? if its present in localstorage or not

Comment: I see nothing weird or changing in localstorage, color does save in localstorage. very weird

Comment: I did and it is a bootstrap problem. When I added a the fully bootstrap library, it changed to a bootstrap color. But when I deleted the bootstrap code. the button changed to the color picker code. Now I need to figure out how I am going to fix this

Comment: My pleasure. Happy that it helped you